# Composer: package installation requires svn/git?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, composer-php

How can I tell which packages require which version control?
For example, I have the following Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "sample/app",
    "description": "sample app",
    "require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*",
    "smarty/smarty": "dev-trunk",
    "zend/gdata": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

The smarty lib gave me a runtime exception because I didn't have svn installed.
Compared this to zend/gdata which gives a runtime exception if git is not installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have git and svn installed, you can usually just use `composer install --prefer-dist` which will try to download zip files as long as possible. For packages using custom svn repositories however like smarty does, this is not yet possible and for those you really need svn installed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  But I found it odd that I didn't see any mention in docs or web searches I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the dependency to subversion you could do it with a private repository like that: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2

But this way you have to update the version number in the private repository if you want to update smarty in the future.